# Clipping raster image using coordinates from CSV file with Python

Tags: python, raster, gdal, clip, extents

I am trying to clip a raster image into a small image using coordinates in a CSV file. In the CSV file, I have minx,maxx,miny,maxy as the coordinates which makes the bounding box and clips the images.

I have a total of 100,000 coordinates and it will create 50,000 images. I am trying to number the images in ascending numbers. Example 0,1,2,3.... till 50,000. The problem is that when clipping it's escaping some images and only clipping 26,000 images. I just cannot find the bug in my code.

I thought it was the coordinate but when checking the coordinates it seems fine, the bug somehow is in my code.

```py
import pandas as pd 
from osgeo import gdal

df = pd.read_csv("G:\\satellite\\align\\satellite.txt")
fs = gdal.Open('G:\\satellite\\align\\satellite.tif')

i, j = 0, 0

while True:
    minx = df.iloc[i][0]
    miny = df.iloc[i][1]
    maxx = df.iloc[i+1][0]
    maxy = df.iloc[i+1][1]
    
    out_tif = r"G:\\satellite\\training_images\\satellite_rename\\{0}.tif".format(j)
    ds = gdal.Translate(out_tif, fs, projWin = [minx, miny, maxx, maxy])
    
    j = j+1
    i += 2
    if i > 100000: # The iteration depends on how many co-ordinates you have
        break
```

Comment: are your coordinates and  rasters in the same projection?

Comment: Yes i took the coordinates from point feature class and they are in the same projection

Comment: another question. have you stopped the process after one clip to view it? along with the coordinates. does the clip make sense?

Comment: why not host the Geotiff file in a geoserver as a wms service ? That way you can access parts of it using any desired bounding box. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015079/how-to-serve-tiff-wms-imagery-through-geoserver

Answer (score 0):

According to [gdal python docs](https://gdal.org/python/):

*projWin --- subwindow in projected coordinates to extract: [ulx, uly, lrx, lry]*

*uly* would be 'upper-left' which corresponds to a maximum for y. Try the following for your *projWin*:

```
projWin = [minx, maxy, maxx, miny]
```

It could also explain why your script stops making crops. If the raster is not square (they rarely are) then at some point in your iteration the coordinates may be *out of bounds*, so to speak, and thus no crop.

Comment: I tired this and it directly throws error. One weird thing is i also have other images  and the same numbers are not being cropped.